# How to import the dymo.framework in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, dymo

I am trying to import `dymo.connect.framework` into my Angular project. I'm trying to follow the SDK support of dymo. They only explain this for JavaScript. I also followed [this](https://www.mymiller.name/wordpress/programming/angular/angular-dymo-label-printer/) explanation.

Unfortunately, there is not a lot information on this to be found yet. I downloaded their `dymo.connect.framework.full.js` from [GitHub](https://github.com/dymosoftware/dymo-connect-framework/blob/master/dymo.connect.framework.full.js), and placed it inside my assets like this: `assets/js/dymo/dymo.connect.framework.full.js`.

Afterwards, I tried to import it in my component like this:

```
import "../../assets/js/dymo/dymo.connect.framework.full";
```

But I am unable to use it. How can I use this JavaScript asset inside my `component.ts`? How do I import it and declare it?

UPDATE:
added the framework in my scripts from `angular.json` as suggested.

```
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
  {
    "input": "src/assets/js/dymo/dymo.connect.framework.full.js",
    "bundleName": "dymo"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `scripts` section of `angular.json`. ([See](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#styles-and-scripts-configuration))

You will have to find corresponding `d.ts` file or create your own or just use as `any`:

```
window['dymo'].label.framework.init()
```

Comment: I've added it in my scripts below my bootstrap like this:                                                             "scripts": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
              { 
                "input":"src/assets/js/dymo/dymo.connect.framework.full.js",
                "bundleName": "dymo"
              }
            ]                                                                                                                                but I don't understand the second part, corresponding d.ts file of what?

Comment: See here https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/dymo-label-framework It's quite old, I don't know if it is a good option.

Comment: I tried to initiate like this. Init() is not possible but I can acces functions from the framework directly. But When I compile it gives error on ['dymo'] --> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.

Answer (score 0):

The dymo site is misleading. You will be lead to the SDK where you can find files. But the JS file there is corrupted. Don't use anything from the SDK. Use the the normal js (not the full) from [here](https://github.com/dymosoftware/dymo-connect-framework/blob/master/README.md) and follow those instructions. Add it like [@kemsky says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76567080/23264330) inside your scripts in the `angular.json` file.

Then you can declare it even more simply in the `.ts` file where you want to use it (I'm working with Angular 15) like  this, right between your imports and where `@Component` starts:

```
declare var dymo:any;
```

You don't need `;` in TypeScript. I just do it out of habit.